# Free, easy way for client to add logo to a PDF?

Tags: pdf, software-recommendation, tools

I have designed a 2-page flyer for a client and left a blank top right corner. Their partners (apparently many partners) are supposed to open this flyer in PDF and add their own logo in that blank space on the first page and resave as PDF.

While I can easily do this via InDesign, it seems the partners need to be able to add their logo internally, so.. any free, lightweight, not complicated tool to recommend for this?

Comment: There's a very simple online editor here: https://smallpdf.com/edit-pdf  I can't make any recommendation though. Perhaps try it out first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they have Adobe Acrobat PRO they can easily add an image or vector to the pdf by using the EDIT PDF tool. 
[image: Edit PDF tool in Adobe Acrobat PRO]

Chances are they do not have Adobe Acrobat Pro, so they can use Open Source PDF editor such as

1. [Libre Office Draw](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/)
2. [PDFedit](http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html)
3. Web tools

**Web tools:** As Billy Kerr mentioned, you can show your client's partners tools such as [Small PDF](https://smallpdf.com/edit-pdf) which you allow you to add an image to the PDF, with easy **size** and **position adjustments**.

I went further and checked if the PDF saved by Small PDF kept the formatting for printing, and it does! Everything remains the same, color scheme, vectors, etc...

So printing will be no problem for you client's partners.

Comment: Acrobat Pro was the obvious choice, but these 'partners' have no connection with the design field, and probably no need for Acrobat Pro outside this scope, so they would have to purchase Acrobat Pro for this specific purpose, which is very unlikely. Yeap, I did try Small PDF myself and seems to do the job, in fact already recommended this to the client. thanks

Comment: @Lucian glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Inkscape can open and save PDFs - while that can be a fairly complicated solution, I've had surprisingly good luck teaching unskilled endusers how to use complex software to do one very specific task (just show them what buttons to click and warn them to never click anything else).

Alternately, there's a bit of a hack-ey workaround with PDF form buttons you can try: 
https://answers.acrobatusers.com/adding-image-field-form-q41825.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would talk to the client and explain that there are two options:

### 1. Pro Work.

If the PDF is intended for professional print, then you can not leave to chance the output PDF, yes they could use something, but Are you sure the color profiles, text, compression, and resolution will be re-saved correctly?

If not, they have to send their logos up to an email address on a specific date and have the logos reviewed on a technical basis if they work for the quality they need for the project.

### 2. Amateur work.

Let's say it needs to be printed in the office, or something. It probably can be could be prepared on a program that everyone has, Word? PowerPoint?

It could be opened on a program everyone can have, probably Inkscape? Scribus?

Or prepared on an online platform. There is a library called Fpdf http://www.fpdf.org/ where you can put a high-resolution image, a form and the class can merge the two on a PDF.